# Does attr(xyz) function work on only those elements which have that particular attribute?

Tags: html, css

Consider the following code:

```css
a:before {
  content: "(" attr(hre)")";
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<a>First line <br></a>
<a hre="No Line"> This is styled with attr() function </a>
```

When we run the script *No Line* appears before the second `anchor` element only. But the brackets appear before both the `anchor` elements.

Does the `attr()`function work on only those elements which have that particular attribute? Is `attr()` defined this way?

Comment: attr(attribute) Sets the content as one of the selector's attribute

Comment: I got that. E.g. we usually have different values of `href` for different `anchor` elements, then attr(attribute) sets the content as of the selected element's attribute's value.

Comment: You answered your own question or I misunderstood. What are you trying to achieve? in CSS the attr() expression does not care what the actual value is, so it just outputs it. @user31782

Comment: @Aziz From first reading at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/attr) it appeared to me if the attr(attribute) function just inserts the value of `attribute` wherever it is called. May be I mistook it. The second line of mdn article(_It can be used on pseudo-elements..._) was very difficult to understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does the `attr()`function works on only those elements which have that particular attribute? Is `attr()` defined this way?

[Yes.](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/generate.html#x18) When an attribute referenced by `attr()` is missing from the element, `attr()` returns an empty string. It does not affect the other strings you may have specified for the `content` property, which is why the brackets appear for both elements.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this with [attribute selector](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_attribute_selectors.asp)

```css
a[hre]:before {
  content: "(" attr(hre)")";
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<a>First line <br></a>
<a hre="No Line"> This is styled with attr() function </a>
```

Comment: This is what I did to w3school https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/w3schools-hider/igiahejkpbnbnekdaefddmdceocmjpll/related